# How to run the same node file multiple times simultaneously in linux?

Tags: linux, node.js

I need to run the same `nohup node app.js &` simultaneously in multiple processes.

Comment: run the command multiple times?

Comment: what do you mean by `run simultaneously`?

Comment: i need the same command to be running parallelly in multiple processes.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you want to run this command for example five times from the same shell (in the same terminal), so that they all start almost immediately and keep running?

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in a loop:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    nohup node app.js &
done
```

Comment: In `zsh`: `repeat 10 { nohup node app.js &; }`